# VS2012 Premium: "Data Sources" menu item is missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, datasource

I am using VS2012 Premium. I do not have a menu item to launch the Data Sources window. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yft2c9ad.aspx) I should have a menu item:

> On the menu bar, choose View, Other Windows, Data Sources (or choose the Shift+Alt+D keys).

but I have no such item.

The shortcut doesn't work either. I have reset the shortcut from Shift+Alt+D (which drops down the Debug menu item) to something else but this still does not display the window.

I have created a new VS solution which is not an MVC website (a WCF application) to address [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7589876/1412915) that the option is hidden in MVC sites.

I have also run `devenv /ResetSettings` 
as suggested on this [MSDN forum posting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/91ecf79f-3dce-4a7e-88c2-48936286c9bb/).

Has anyone any ideas how I can launch the Data Sources window?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the project type you choose. For instance, a *WCF Service Application* project will not show you this option, while *WCF Service Library* project will show you the option.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I had was that my Report Data pane went missing when working with RDLC files.

Click somewhere on your main design working area (in my case the design area for the RDLC I am updating).

Then go to the View menu -> Report Data.

The Data Sources and DataSets are now available in the Report Data pane.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution for some:

I've noticed that the View > Other Windows > Data Sources option is not available when the active file in the main window is a .sql query file (I'm sure this would be the case for other types of files as well).

In this case, simply selecting a file associated with the solution will make the View > Other Windows > Data Sources option available again.